# How to get SSH PuTTY bookmarks / sessions synchronized?

Tags: putty

As sysadmin working in IT consulting, I have a lot of SSH PuTTY (managed by SuperPutty) sessions, and also, I have 2 computers, and a few virtual machines and a Terminal Server with Putty in which I have all these sessions.

Is there a way to synchronize all those putty sessions,or any SSH client that has this functionality?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I wanted to say, automatically

Comment: I've seen this done in the past with a login script that added the entries for various putty hosts to the user's registry when they login.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a windows guy. But i know our windows people export the session list and keep it in git and then pull it from git onto another machine and merge that "putty-registry.reg" file by right clicking it onto the new machine. This is the link how to export/import it

[LINK](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/putty-session.html)

But i do not think putty has anything built-in for this particular purpose.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The excellent putty faq contains a python script that generates a windows .reg file. You'll probably be able to customise it to what you want to do (be careful with your registry though)

Putty Faq:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-disksettings

A.2.9 Is there an option to turn off the annoying host key prompts?

> If you have host keys available in the common known_hosts format, we
>   have a script called kh2reg.py to convert them to a Windows .REG file,
>   which can be installed ahead of time by double-clicking or using
>   REGEDIT.

This link might also be helpful:

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2007/02/01/howto-transfer-your-putty-settings-between-computers/

Answer (score -1):

It would be awfully cool if the Windows Sync stuff synhronized the putty part of the user's registry--but it doesn't.

One possible solution would be to store a file in OneDrive (or some shared loction) and write a script that runs on logon and dumps the putty part of the registry into a file and then compares with previous run in OneDrive with diff and then merges them and sucks in the changes back into the registry.

Kudos to anyone who writes this script!  (I may do so on some rainy day).

Personally I find having to depend on a file in OneDrive not a great solution but I can't think of any other way to do this at this time.